# PEAR MDB2 seek() & count() in MDB2_Iterator

Tags: php, pear, mdb2

I am having trouble with `MDB2_Iterator`, this is an old project which is being moved to a new  server.

The function in `MDB2_Iterator` for `count()` is below:

```
public function count()
{
    if ($this->result) {
        return $this->result->numRows();
    }
    return false;
}
```

`$this->result` is a MySql Resource and so `numRows()` fails.

Error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function numRows() on a non-object in /usr/share/pear/MDB2/Iterator.php on line 246

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add the error message?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function numRows() on a non-object in /usr/share/pear/MDB2/Iterator.php on line 246

Comment: Result is not an object, so you search where result is set.

Comment: @RageZ right of course. But rather than doing that and hunting through PEAR I thought I would post on here and attempt to find someone else who has had the same issue.